# Can't get Ghostscript "viewraw.ps" or "viewrgb.ps" programs to work (scrambled output)

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, ghostscript

I've had good results in the past using the "viewjpeg.ps" PostScript program included with Ghostscript to place JPEG images into generated PDFs. Now I'm trying to do the same for bitmaps, and I just haven't been able to make it work. My hunch is that the program I need is either "viewraw.ps" or "viewrgb.ps," and I can see that the parameters expected will be a bit different from those passed to "viewjpeg.ps."

So far this is what I have:

**"C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.10\bin\gswin64c.exe" -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -DNOSAFER -r200x200 -sOutputFile=o.pdf z:\home\dell\reporting\viewrgb.ps  -c "(out002.bmp) 6800 viewrgb"**

This gets pretty close to what I want, but my bitmap (though clearly identifiable) is scrambled in the output PDF: compressed vertically, upside-down, and somewhat wrong in color.

I have attempted to address these issues by tweaking the "width" parameter (6800 above). My bitmap is 1,700 pixels wide, and uses 4 bytes per pixel, so 1,700 * 4 = 6,800 seemed like a logical choice. I've also tried 1,700 (width in pixels) and 54,400 (bits per image row). 5,100 (3 * 1,700) seemed to work best, but it's still wrong.

Note that "viewjpeg.ps" does not expect a "width" parameter, so I haven't had to deal with this before. (It was an examination of "viewrgb.ps" that made me realize this parameter was required.)

Can anyone spot my mistake, or maybe point me to an example that uses "viewraw.ps" or "viewrgb.ps"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't said (or I missed it) what format your 'bitmaps' are, and you haven't supplied an example to look at so I can't tell (or experiment).

You say your output is 4 bytes per pixel so that's either CMYK or something like RGBa. Either way viewrgb isn't going to work, because it only expects 3 channels. It's intended to view the output of the Ghostscript bitrgb device.

Viewraw just reads raw data, straight image samples,  no header IIRC and it's **CMYK**, so unless your 4 bytes are CMYK then it's not going to be correct either.

Since both of these are RAW format, they don't expect a header, if your image format includes a header, then that's going to be treated as image data which will certainly cause the image to be drawn incorrectly.

Both of these PostScript programs will display a usage message on the back channel if you invoke them incorrectly.

You don't need -dNOSAFER with such an old version of Ghostscript (9.10).

-r has little effect on pdfwrite and will have no effect at all when you feed it an image as input; you should probably omit that.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, -r and -dNOSAFER were definitely shots in the dark. The file I'm using does have a header, i.e. is not "raw." Sounds like if I'm going to use Ghostscript for this I'll need my own PostScript program. Or maybe I can output true raw data... I do control the code writing out the bitmap.

Comment: If you can control the format then you could presumably write out anything convenient. You might like to look at the Portable Pixmap format (PPM), there's a viewpbm.ps program which will open PPM files. The Wikipedia entry is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format#PPM_example Its a simple enough format. Alternatively you can of course write a PostScript program to read many data formats, there are a number of view....ps files which would probably give you some pointers if you wanted to do that. Of course you could also write a PostScript program containing a btimap as your output :-)